# Why is IIS redirecting to the default website when browsing my SSL-secured wildcard domain?

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, wildcard, windows-server-2016

I have hosted a simple website that says **"Hello in internal server"** in IIS with an SSL wildcard certificate but when I browse the URL it redirects me to the default website of IIS.
I hope you can advise me.

[image]
[image][image]

I have done Is shown in the pictures but not working.

Comment: What browser are you using? If you don't use a well recognized browser to send out SNI compatible requests, IIS won't be able to resolve them to the right site.

Comment: Your browser may cache the page you browsed before, I suggest you try clearing your browser cache or try accessing the website from a different browser.

Comment: Have you checked the default file set for the website? Try to access the website with the file name.

Comment: also check if the website is stopped in IIS